# Learning Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I am planning to learn Java Web Services and going through different options but got stuck on which resource to follow.

I have gone through the online documentation at [Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html), after following that I just got the basics about `JAX-WS` and `RESTful`, but it gave very basic example that works with `NetBeans` and `Glassfish` server.

Then I started with [Java 7 JAX-WS Web Services](http://www.amazon.in/Java-7-JAX-WS-Web-Services-ebook/dp/B00850BHFY) and saw that it also covers basics with lot of screenshots.

Next I went through the other documentation at [Web Services tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/), but here the explanation is completely different from my first link and I have not seen where the explanation is given for `RESTful` and `JAX-WS`.

Now I am planning to go through the [Java Webservices Up and and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521134.do), but observed that it was released in 2009, so it wont cover any latest updates. Please let me know if this book is fine to learn the fundamentals as I observed that this book was referred by many experienced guys.

Please help me to point the correct resource on how to learn Java web-services. Please suggest if there are any books that I can refer to?

I prefer using `Eclipse` with `Tomcat/Jboss/Weblogic` servers

Comment: It is really disappointing to see person with almost year experience on SO asking off-topic questions. Take a look at point 5 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Pshemo, but I have not found any other forums for web-services to ask this question, atleast I hope I will get some pointers this time so I can start with correct resource before it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 2nd edition of the "Java Web Services Up and running" by the same author which was released on August 2013, the content has been updated with new stuff especially for the "Rest" topic.